# how to get percentage for groupby size

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to get percentages

```
df.groupby(['state', 'approved_or_not']).size()

Output:

school_state  project_is_approved
AK            0                         55
              1                        290
AL            0                        256
              1                       1506
AR            0                        177
              1                        872
AZ            0                        347
              1                       1800
```

which is good but what I want is percentages instead of counts.

```
school_state  project_is_approved
AK            0                        0.16
              1                        0.84
AL            0                        0.14
              1                        0.86
```

I tried and couldn't figure out a way. Appreciate if someone can help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with parameter `normalize=True`:

```
df.groupby('state')['approved_or_not'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

L = list('ABC')
df = pd.DataFrame({'state':np.random.choice(L, size=10),
                   'approved_or_not':np.random.choice([0,1], size=10)})
print (df)
  state  approved_or_not
0     A                0
1     C                0
2     B                1
3     A                0
4     C                1
5     C                1
6     A                0
7     B                0
8     A                0
9     C                1
```

---

```
a = df.groupby(['state', 'approved_or_not']).size()
print (a)
A      0                  4
B      0                  1
       1                  1
C      0                  1
       1                  3
dtype: int64

a = df.groupby('state')['approved_or_not'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print (a)
state  approved_or_not
A      0                  1.00
B      0                  0.50
       1                  0.50
C      1                  0.75
       0                  0.25
Name: approved_or_not, dtype: float64
```

EDIT: You can divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with `sum` per first level `state`:

```
a = df.groupby(['state', 'approved_or_not']).size()

a = a.div(a.sum(level=0), level=0)
print (a)
state  approved_or_not
A      0                  1.00
B      0                  0.50
       1                  0.50
C      0                  0.25
       1                  0.75
dtype: float64
```

Comment: jezrael, Is it possible to get percentages without using value counts?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved using an aggregate function.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(316)
```

`lst = ['Karnataka', 'Tamil Nadu', 'Kerala']`

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'state':np.random.choice(lst, size=10),
                   'approved_or_not':np.random.choice([2,4], size=10)})
```

`print (data)`

`data.groupby(['state', 'approved_or_not']).agg({'approved_or_not': ["size", "mean"]})`

**Output**

```
                                approved_or_not
                                size    mean
    state   approved_or_not     
Karnataka                2      4        2
Kerala                   2      1        2
                         4      3        4
Tamil Nadu               2      1        2
                         4      1        4
```